# How to store each new transaction in multiple/different blocks

Tags: web3js, transactions, ganache

How can I connect to Ganache so each time I add to the blockchain the transaction is stored in the next block. I have an issue that each time I add to the blockchain it gets added to the same block address. I am using React to add the date to the blockchain. However, I have init web3 with ABI and Address(which all the transactions are stored in).

Comment: I think typically Ganache mines a new block for each transaction - especially if there is some time delay between them. Also, I'm not sure what you mean with "block address", since blocks don't have an address.

Comment: In ganache,there is a list of accounts each has it is own account address. There is a code that I am trying to follow but it is not working here: https://github.com/dappuniversity/eth-todo-list. Not sure why it is not working with me. I am thinking it is because of the node, npm, truffle verisons but not sure.

Comment: You can set which address sends the transaction. How you do that depends on the libraries you are using.